# Per service configuration in Consul

Tags: consul

Consul currently supports distributed configuration, where-in key/value config is replicated across servers. Supposing I have one service per server, how do I configure consul to have unique configuration per service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a base namespace to each service. Lets say you have prod and dev configs for the same service. You can have different configuration KV's in /prd/service/key/value and /dev/service/key/value. Then you can add appropriate acl's to each base namespace for access controls.